# How to create a logging system for a system that serves users?

Tags: node.js, database, design-patterns, rabbitmq, scalability

I have a system (in NODE.JS) that servers users (around 10000 users) and I want to write to the database every step that they do.

For example:

> 1.When a user logs in / logs out - write to the DB
>
> 2.When user changed his profile - also
>
> 3.User made some kind of transaction ... etc

I don't want to add a database action to every action that the user does , since it takes more process time and on a larger scale there might be delays.

What would be the best approach to write to the DB every step without too much delays ?

Comment: Are you concerned about overloading the database with requests and queries or your node app?

Comment: Why would you think that your logging effort would be less load for the server than database actions (which have been optimized by the database developers)?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of possibilities here. Though before I get into them, I'm not sure you need to worry too much about the extra overhead of a few database calls per request. Node is very efficient when it comes to handling requests since everything happens asynchronously. Also, databases are generally designed to handle this kind of traffic.

That being said, if you've tried it the simple way of simply calling the database when you want to log, you have several options:

1. write log entries to file and then process them in batch at a later time when traffic is lower.
2. use a separate database for logging that won't affect your main database
3. Use a log management system like [splunk](https://www.splunk.com/) instead of a database.
4. Use stored procedures or database triggers to ensure all database calls are logged without making a separate call to the database to do it.